# Flutter Keyboard show and immediately disappeared at textfied in listview

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a list view and want to edit the Tile's title. When user click the edit icon, text widget change to TextField. Once user tap the textfield, keyboard show and immediately disappeared.

May I know what is the issue?

```
class EditableListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Favourite favourite;
  final Function onChanged;
  final Function onTap;
  const EditableListTile(
  {Key? key,
  required this.favourite,
  required this.onChanged,
  required this.onTap})
  : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditableListTileState createState() => _EditableListTileState();
}

class _EditableListTileState extends State<EditableListTile> {
  Favourite? favourite;

  late bool _isEditingMode;

  late TextEditingController _titleEditingController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    favourite = widget.favourite;
    _isEditingMode = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        widget.onTap(favourite);
      },
      leading: leadingWidget,
      title: titleWidget,
      trailing: tralingButton,
    );
  }

  Widget get leadingWidget {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 32,
      child: FolderIcon(
        color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color!,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get titleWidget {
    if (_isEditingMode) {
      _titleEditingController = TextEditingController(text: favourite?.name);
      return TextField(
        controller: _titleEditingController,
      );
    } else {
      return Text(favourite!.name);
    }
  }

  Widget get tralingButton {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        (favourite?.isDefault == false)
            ? (_isEditingMode
                ? IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.check),
                    onPressed: saveChange,
                 )
                : IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                    onPressed: _toggleMode,
              ))
            : Container(),
        _isEditingMode
            ? IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined),
                onPressed: cancelChange,
              )
            : Container()
      ],
    );
  }

  void _toggleMode() {
    setState(() {
      _isEditingMode = !_isEditingMode;
    });
  }

  void cancelChange() {
    setState(() {
      _isEditingMode = !_isEditingMode;
    });
  }

  void saveChange() {
    favourite!.name = _titleEditingController.text;
    _toggleMode();
    widget.onChanged(favourite!);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you get this error because you initialized the `TextEdittingController` inside the `titleWidget`. every time the widget rebuild, create a new instance of `TextEdittingController`.

on top of your clas change it like this

```
// late TextEditingController _titleEditingController;  <== Change This
TextEditingController _titleEditingController = TextEditingController();
```

in `titleWidget` change your code to this.

```
Widget get titleWidget {
    if (_isEditingMode) {
      _titleEditingController.text = favourite?.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. I did changed what you suggest. But real culprit is key in ListView.seperate. I used key : UniqueKey(). If I change to ValueKey(state.favourites[index]), it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Real culprit is key in ListView.seperate. I used key : UniqueKey(). If I change to ValueKey(state.favourites[index]), it is working now.

I used key : UniqueKey() because I have onDismissed but one of the item, want to trigger onDismissed but don't want to dismissed.

Let's say, item is folder name and if user delete the item, delete the folder and delete all the files under that folder. But one folder is system generated and don't want user to delete that folder but let them to delete files. So we call confirmDismiss and tell the user that it is system generated folder and only will delete files.

But list view don't allow. So I found out the UniqueKey is work
around. So edit is importance. So that I take out UniqueKey.

Comment: I can confirm using anything except for UniqueKey() seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like Alex Aung's answer above, they're right that the use of UniqueKey() is a problem .

In my case I had an action button that pushed a page route to the navigator. On the content view *(GameView)* I had a **UniqueKey()** set and it was responsible for series of issues with input fields downstream.

Any time I set this back to UniqueKey(), any clicking inside a downstream **TextFormField** causes the Keyboard open then immediately close.

```
  Widget getActionButton() {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        final Account account = Account("test@test.com");
        widget.viewModels.gamesModel.load(account);
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => GamesView(
                    key: Key("GameView"),            // UniqueKey() is a problem here.
                    account: account,
                    viewModels: widget.viewModels,
                )
            )
        );
      },
      tooltip: 'Save Changes',
      child: Icon(Icons.save),
    );
  }
```